# Wix::heat, Is it possible to add child element under component element while harvesting?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, heat

Basically i want to add `<Condition>0</Condition>` element under the `<Component>..</Component>` element when i harvest a directory using heat.exe

I should look like below

```
  <Component Id='JapaneseFlag' Guid='{4CB0C1EE-8370-4880-B172-CF1E9F7308F7}'>
     <File Id='JaFlag' Source='.\ja.png'></File>
     <Condition>INSTALLEDSWVERSION = "XYZ"</Condition>
  </Component>
```

and i also want the conditional feature for the above component under the feature element, like

```
  <Feature Id='JA_Flag' Title='Japanese Flag' Level='1'>
     <Condition Level='0'>NOT (INSTALLEDSWVERSION = "XYZ")</Condition>
     <ComponentRef Id='JapaneseFlag'/>
  </Feature>
```

Is this possible using heat?

if not, So Is there any way to do this dynamically?

Any clue would help me to google further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use xslt to transform the generated wxs file.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034798/wix-installer-using-xslt-with-heat-exe-to-update-attributes) for example.